# check login and sessions

Tags: php, session-cookies

I'm making API to simple forum ,, Now trying to check Login with php

on the control page : showForums.php

```
<?php require_once('session.php');?>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>TheForums</title>
</head> 
<body>

<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require_once('fourmsAPI.php');
/*
function tinyf_forums_get($extra ='')
{
    global $tf_handle;
    $query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM `forums` %s",$extra );
    $qresult = mysqli_query($tf_handle, $query);

    if (!$qresult)
        return NULL;
    $recount = mysqli_num_rows($qresult);
    if ($recount == 0)
        return NULL ;
    $forums = array();
    for($i = 0 ; $i < $recount ; $i++)
        $users[count($forums)] = mysqli_fetch_object($qresult);
    //mysql_free_result($qresult);

    return $forums;

}
*/
$forums = tinyf_forums_get();
if($forums == NULL)
{
    die('problem');
}
$fcount = count($forums);
if($fcount == 0)
{
    die('No Forums ');
}
if($_SESSION['user_info'] == false){
    echo '<a href = "login.php">Login!</a>';
}
else{
    $uname = $_SESSION['user_info']->name ;
    echo '<a href = "logout.php">'.$uname.' -- Logout!'.'</a>' ;
}
?>

<br/>

<ul type = "square">
<?php
for($i = 0 ; $i < $fcount ; $i++)
{
    $forum = $forums[$i];
    echo "<li><a href = \"forum.php?id=$forum->id\"> $forum->title <a/> <br/> $forum->desc --";
    if($_SESSION['user_info']->isadmin ==1){
        echo " <a href = \"deleteForum.php?id=$forum->id\"> Delete <a/> | <a href = \"modifyForum.php?id=$forum->id\"> edit <a/> " ;
    }
    echo "<br/>  </li>"; //$array -> 

}
?>  
</ul>   

</body>
</html>
```

> Error: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/tinyforum/showForums.php on line 62

session.php

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['user_info'])){
    $_SESSION['user_info'] = false ;
}
?>
```

i expected the if statement won't be executed

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: i get error: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/tinyforum/showForums.php on line 62

Comment: which one is line 62 ?

Comment: You might need `session_start()` at the start of your code. Also, `$_SESSION['user_info']->isadmin ==1` should possibly be `$_SESSION['user_info']['isadmin'] ==1` but I am not entirely sure. You might need to show more information about your code for that.

Comment: @Maximus2012 if($_SESSION['user_info']->isadmin ==1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The if statement check has to execute if the loop executes. The inside part does not execute as you expected. The error you're getting is from the condition check. If the user is not logged in, your code is equivalent to

```
if(null->isadmin ==1){
    echo " <a href = \"deleteForum.php?id=$forum->id\"> Delete <a/> | <a href = \"modifyForum.php?id=$forum->id\"> edit <a/> " ;
}
```

Which obviously yields an error. You can check that the session is set first or use the `@` operator.

Comment: i tried @ and it helped me so ...@ operator will avoid the problem if the user didn't login ?

Comment: if(@$_SESSION['user_info']->isadmin ==1){
  echo " <a href = \"deleteForum.php?id=$forum->id\"> Delete <a/> | <a href = \"modifyForum.php?id=$forum->id\"> edit <a/> " ;
 } that what u mean ?

Comment: Take a look at [this community wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php). The `@` operator just tells PHP to shut up and not display warnings. It's *ok* in this case (checking if the user is null would be better), but please don't abuse it as it hides important errors. This would be better: `if($_SESSION['user_info'] && $_SESSION['user_info']->isadmin === 1) {}`

Comment: if($_SESSION['user_info'] && $_SESSION['user_info']->isadmin == 1) worked too :) but $_SESSION['user_info'] means if the user log in will be true ?

Comment: The `&&` means that both conditions have to be true for the if statement to execute the inside. First it checks if the user is set, then the admin privileges. For admins, this ends up being `true && true` which evaluates to true. Logged in non-admins end up as `true && false`, so they don't see the output. Non-logged in users get `false && false`, so they don't see it either.